# what PSH kernel in intel edison mean? Is it the name of primary bootloader present inside ROM?

Tags: bootloader, rtos, intel-edison

I was going through the logs after booting up the intel edison. I came accross the word. Is it the name of bios?Does it do some security verification like key matching/checking and all ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intel Edison board, more precisely Intel Tangier SoC, has a **Minute IA** (**i486+**, also known as **Pentium ISA** microarchitecture) based MCU (for example, Intel Quark D2000 SoC has it as far as I know) which is part of so called **Platform Services Hub** (PSH). PSH has own Page Cache (to keep RTOS and its applications), LAPIC.  The peripheral, such as DMA and I2C, is shared with **System Controller Unit** (SCU). SCU actually controls PSH.

When system starts MCU boots first. Inside it is a **Viper** RTOS with some modifications, i.e. it has a library to support sensors.

There is no information available from Intel regarding use of open source RTOS, such as **Zephyr**, on PSH.